How to expand a symmetric triple sum?
I'll start with a double sum example:
$$\sum_{n,l}f_{n}f_{l}\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial x_{n}\partial x_{l}} = \sum_{n}f_{n}^{2}\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial x_{n}^{2}}+2\sum_{n<l}f_{n}f_{l}\frac{\partial^{2}g}{\partial x_{n}\partial x_{l}},\qquad n,l \in [1,N]$$
This is not a simplification, but it greatly reduces the number of arithmetic operations needed to evaluate the result. The right hand side is intuitive as we can imagine all the terms arranged on a square grid, then the first sum is the diagonal terms and the second sum is upper (or lower) triangle.
We can also check the number of terms on the left $|N^2|$ and on the right $|N+2(N^2-N)/2=N^2|$, which is correct.
Now for a similar triple sum seems to expand like this:
$$\sum_{m,n,l}f_{m} f_{n}f_{l}\frac{\partial^{3} g}{\partial x_{m}\partial x_{n}\partial x_{l}} = \sum_{n}f_{n}^{3}\frac{\partial^{3}g}{\partial x_{n}^{3}}+3\sum_{n\neq l}f_{n}^{2}f_{l}\frac{\partial^{3}g}{\partial x_{n}^{2}\partial x_{l}}+\sum_{m\neq n\neq l}f_{m}f_{n}f_{l}\frac{\partial^{3}g}{\partial x_{m}\partial x_{n}\partial x_{l}}$$
But it's not very helpful, since there's hardly any gain in the number of operations reduced. So what am I missing?
My combinatorics is bad, it's my weakest area of math.

you can substitute the last with $6\sum_{m<n<l}$

@Exodd, thank you! I wasn't sure
